# Angular single page application not interpreting html tags

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I'd like to be able to load a partial view inside my html with AngularJS.

The problem I have, is that when I do something like that :

```
mySite.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/:slug', { templateUrl: '/Include', controller: 'RouteController' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' });
}]);

mySite.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    $http.get('/Index').success(function (data) {
        $rootScope.pages = data;
    });

    $scope.$on('routeLoaded', function (event, args) {
        $scope.slug = args.slug;
    });
}]);

mySite.controller('RouteController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    var slug = $routeParams.slug;

    $scope.$emit('routeLoaded', { slug: slug });
    $scope.page = $rootScope.pages;
}]);
```

I've inserted this inside my "master view"

```
<div data-ng-view></div>
```

And the partial view is as simple as this :

```
<div>{{page}}</div>
```

I receive HTML code, and this HTML code is displayed without being interpreted.

edit : here is a screenshot of what I get
[image: screenshot]

Comment: This might be because of the asynchronous http request. So `$scope.page = $rootScope.pages;` is getting executed before `$rootScope.pages = data;` does.

Comment: You're right, but this is not the problem actually. In fact, sometimes, I get nothing, and sometimes, I get html not interpreted

Comment: You mean the `page` variable contains HTML tags and they display as tags (e.g. `<b>xxx</b>` instead of **xxx**)?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos yes

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Then you might want to have a look at `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

Comment: @CodeHater thank you, it worked. Can you write it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display HTML content in angular version 1.0.7:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="page"></div>
```

Note: In the recent versions, `ng-bind-html-unsafe` dont work anymore and you would need to inject `ngSanitize` as a dependency to your app module.

Answer (score 2):

The `{{...}}` does not allow HTML content for security reasons. You may use `ng-include` as follows instead, to do what I presume you want:

```
<div data-ng-view>
    <div ng-include="url.to.page.with.content"></div>
</div>
```

Where `url.to.page.with.content` is a variable containing e.g. `"/Index"`, the path to your HTML template.

Comment: My objective is to create a single page application. The inside of the ng-view must change often